# $n=\dim V$. Then $V=\ker(T^n)\oplus\mathrm{range}(T^n)$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I trying to solve the following problem. The question is from a past exam.

> Suppose that $V$ is a finite dimensional vector space over a field $K$. Let $T: V\rightarrow V$ be a linear operator. If $n=\dim V$, then $V=\ker(T^n)\oplus\mathrm{range}(T^n)$

**Attempt/Thoughts**.
If I can show that $\ker(T^n)\cap \mathrm{range}T^n={0}$ then we are done. To show this I need the following claim. (At least this is what I think). I claim that $\ker(T^{2n}) \subseteq \ker(T^n)$. I am stuck on trying to prove this. I know that

> $\ker(T) \subseteq \ker(T^2) \subseteq \ker(T^3) \subseteq \cdots$

So this set of inclusions has to stop at some point since we are in the finite dimensional case(?). If there is some $r\geq0$ such that $\ker(T^{r})=\ker(T^{r+1})$ then I can easily prove my claim. But I don't know how to make this precise.

Can somebody help?

Thanks

Comment: If you know a bit of commutative algebra, then it seems easy. A finitely generated module over Noetherian ring is a Noetherian module, and hence every increasing chain of inclusion will terminate at some point. Probably you can use the argument: if $\ker T=\ker T^{2}$, then we are done, otherwise, $\ker T\subset \ker T^{2}$ (strict inclusion) and the dimension is strictly less. Then move on to $\ker T^{2}\subseteq \ker T^{3}$. If they are equal, done, otherwise the dimension is 1 less than the other ... until it stops at some point because of finite dimension of $V$.

Comment: A subspace of a finite dimensional space is finite dimensional. If you have an ascending chain of subspaces $V_1 \subsetneqq \ldots \subsetneqqV_i \subsetneqq V_{i+1} \subsetneqq \ldots$ that does not terminate, each time the dimension is increasing by one and so this would contradict finite dimensionality of your space.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of considering the chain $\ker(T) \subseteq \ker(T^2) \subseteq \ker(T^3) \subseteq \cdots$, you may consider the ascending chain of **proper** subset inclusion $\ker(T) \subset \ker(T^2) \subset \ker(T^3) \subset \cdots$. Since $V$ is finite dimensional, the dimension of $\ker(T^r)$ cannot keep *strictly* increasing. Therefore there must exist some $r$ that is the first index such that $\ker(T^r)=\ker(T^{r+1})$.

We also have the descending chain $\mathrm{range}(T) \color{green}{\supseteq} \mathrm{range}(T^2) \color{green}{\supseteq} \mathrm{range}(T^3) \color{green}{\supseteq} \cdots$. Therefore, by the rank-nullity theorem,
$$
\mathrm{range}(T) \color{red}{\supset} \mathrm{range}(T^2) \color{red}{\supset} \mathrm{range}(T^3) \color{red}{\supset} \cdots \color{red}{\supset}\mathrm{range}(T^r)=\mathrm{range}(T^{r+1}).
$$
Note that the rank-nullity theorem implies that the inclusions preceding $\mathrm{range}(T^r)$ are strict. It remains to show that

1. $\ker(T^r)\cap\mathrm{range}(T^r)=0$ and hence $V=\ker(T^r)\oplus\mathrm{range}(T^r)$.
2. $r\le n$.
3. $V=\ker(T^n)\oplus\mathrm{range}(T^n)$.

Comment: Do you really mean $V=0$, in $1.$?

Comment: @awllower Ahhh, typos, typos. Thanks for catching that.

Answer (score 2):

This was answered by Robert Israel [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/57642/for-v-vector-space-of-dimension-n-under-mathbb-c-and-t-v-to-v-linear). Here is his proof with some added detail: From the dimension formulas it suffices to show that $$\ker T^{n}\cap\mbox{Im}T^{n}=\{0\}.$$ Assume for contradiction that $0\neq y\in\ker T^{n}\cap\mbox{Im}T^{n}$.
Then $\exists x,T^{n}x=y$, and $0=T^{n}y=T^{2n}x$. Consider the
set of vectors

$$\{\underset{\neq0}{\underbrace{x,Tx,T^{2}x,...,T^{n}x}},T^{n+1}x,...,\underset{=0}{\underbrace{T^{2n}x}\}}$$

Thus, there is an $1\leq\ell\leq n-1$ such that $T^{n+\ell}x\neq0$
but $T^{n+\ell+1}x=0$. Set $z=T^{\ell}x$. Then 
$$T^{n}z\neq0,\, T^{n+1}z=0.$$

This last property implies that $A=\{z,Tz,...,T^{n}z\}$ is linearly
independent: if $${\displaystyle 0=\sum_{i=0}^{n}\alpha_{i}T^{i}z},$$
then we apply $T^{n}$ to both sides to obtain $0=\alpha_{0}T^{n}z$
and therefore $\alpha_{0}=0$. This argument can be repeated to show
that all the $\alpha_{i}$ are zero, as required for linear independence.
Now since $A$ is linearly independent it has at most $n$ elements.
But $|A|=n+1$, which is a contradiction. As Robert Israel notes in his reply, this argument works over any field.

Note also jspecter's reply on the [same](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/57642/for-v-vector-space-of-dimension-n-under-mathbb-c-and-t-v-to-v-linear) page,  which is the kind of proof your instructor probably expected if the exercise was given "over $\mathbb{C}$".